# which is faster way to load images Buffered stream or absolute path in webpage?

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, image

I wanted to know which is faster way to send images to webclient HTML5 and Jquery

> 1. Using direct path to folder structure from Jquery **or**
> 2. Using Ajax call and getting images in buffered stream.

Note :- i am storing images in folder structure and per page i am going to display only 10-15 images.

Comment: using ajax would be smooth idea but exactly I can't say it would be faster... you should have tested by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this using ajax at client side and base64 encoding at server side.
Use JSON to transer all the images.